# leadsource is "web" then update phone number field 123 using workflow

Tags: workflow, field-update, error-messages

I want to do if **LeadSource** Field on **Contact** Object has "web" value then update phone field with `123` using workflow but its given error that

> Formula result is data type (Number), incompatible with expected data type(Phone)

Answer (score 0):

I was setting the **Phone** field value with

> `Value('123')`

and it was giving error. 
Resolved issue by replacing the above with the following

> `123`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.